# How can I check dynamic checkboxes with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox, selection

I am trying to find the easiest way to check change event checkboxes.

I created checkboxes with php script

PHP:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12 servicesCheck" style="margin-top:-10px">
        <?php
        foreach ($data["languageSchool"]["services"] as $service) {
            $required = "";
            $checked = "";
            if ($service["is_required"] == "1") {
                $required = "disabled";
                $checked = "checked";
            }
            echo "<div class='checkbox " . $required . "'>";
            echo "  <label><input id='services' type='checkbox' " . $checked . " " . $required . " value='" . $service["price"] . "'>" . $service["name"] . "</label>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
        ?> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('#servicesCheck :checkbox').change(function () {
    // DO SOMETHING
});
```

What did I do wrong in my code.

Comment: What is `servicesCheck`?

Comment: @Xorifelse I confused class and id jquery selector. servicesCheck is class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the jQuery selector is wrong.
'servicesCheck' in your HTML is a Class not an Id,

```
$('.servicesCheck input:checkbox').change(function () {
// DO SOMETHING
});
```

should work.

Although :checkbox works [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) says: "it is recommended to precede it with a tag name or some other selector"

Answer (score 0):

your php code will generate multiple checkbox with same ID. change it by adding an auto increment suffix.. and also you used `#servicesCheck` in jQuery code, which is not available in this code

Comment: you right I just deal with fix it.

echo "  <label><input id='services" . $service["ID"] . "' type='checkbox'....

Answer (score 0):

Personally I find it easier to specifically target by name attribute as it must exist in the source code as likely multiple check-boxes need a different handling and not the same one.

If you have only 1, [Alvaro's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40566806/4982088) answer will suffice.

```
$('#myloginform input[name=mycheckboxname]:checked').change(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('name'));
});
```